# (Un)setting a cookie in mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, cookies

I'd like to remove a cookie using mod_rewrite but unfortunately the subsequent request (Chrome,FF,Safari) keeps the old cookie value.

Doku ( http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_co ) says:

```
[CO=NAME:VALUE:DOMAIN:lifetime:path:secure:httponly]
```

So my RewriteRule is

```
RewriteRule .* target/ [R=301,CO=NAME:INVALID:.dev.local:-1]
```

Any glues what's wrong?

Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This finally worked for me:

```
RewriteRule .* target/ [R=301,CO=NAME:INVALID:;:-1]
```

Hope it helps someone.