# two domains, one .htaccess, free one from cookie

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, cookieless

I have two domains both pointing to `/var/www`:

- `www.example.com`: main domain, has cookies
- `static.example.com`: cookie-less domain for static content

I now want to free the `static.example.com` domain from cookies using `.htaccess` using following lines:

```
RequestHeader unset Cookie
Header unset Set-Cookie
```

**My problem:**

Since both domains share one `.htaccess` file: How do I make sure these lines only apply to `static.example.com`?

Comment: Seems kind of backwards. The static domain should never send a set-cookie header in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options. Let me show some in order of my preference:

1) create dedicated folder for each domain, your server serves. Then you can also configure each in different way.

2) set cookies correctly. Browser will append cookies only to requests for correct domain - so don't set cookie domain `example.com` but use `www.example.com` and do domain name normalization of your requests - so redirect permanently all requests to `http://example.com` to `http://www.example.com`

3) unset specific cookie using `mod_rewrite` using the `CO` switch. For more details see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000587/unsetting-a-cookie-in-mod-rewrite).